# Change Color of MenuBar, Menu, and MenuItem in Java using the AWT Components

Tags: java, awt

I've been searching around for a bit, but I haven't found an answer as to whether or not it's possible to and how to change the background, text, foreground, selection, and text selection colors of the MenuBar, Menu, and MenuItem AWT components.

So-far I've tried the following solutions, but neither affect any of the colors of any of the Menu-related components. The first solution just attempts to grab the component and change the color and the second tries to change it through the UIManager.

```
// Just an example of what I did, this is not from the code I'm working with.    
MenuBar bar = new MenuBar();
Menu menu = new Menu();
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();

bar.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleComponent().setBackground(Color.RED);
bar.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleComponent().setForeground(Color.BLUE);

menu.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleComponent().setBackground(Color.RED);
menu.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleComponent().setForeground(Color.BLUE);

item.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleComponent().setBackground(Color.RED);
item.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleComponent().setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

--

```
UIManager.put("MenuItem.background", Color.RED);
UIManager.put("MenuItem.foreground", Color.BLUE);
```

I haven't worked much with the AWT components before, so sorry if the answer is obvious.

---

**Update:**

It seems as if using the AWT components is just a bad idea if you're looking to be able to easily change the component colors. I'll be refactoring my code to eliminate as many AWT components in favour of the Swing components and I suggest anyone reading this do the same if at all possible.

Comment: There is difference between Swing and AWT. Do you really need to use the (out of date) AWT API?

Comment: Have you tried just calling setBackground/foreground on the components themselves (instead of the accessible components)?

Comment: As suggested by others go for swing, there is no simple way to achieve it with awt

Comment: @MadProgrammer In a few cases I do need to use the AWT components, but I have managed to rework the code to use a JFrame instead of a Frame. This solved the issue.

As far as I've seen, from poking around the methods of the AWT components, there's no easy or clear way that I can find to change the component colors.

Comment: @Arvind Thanks, I have managed to switch the main portion of the code over to Swing so-far. Hopefully it doesn't cause any odd issues. =P

Comment: In "some" cases, can you specific, out of curiosity ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer No problem, although only one specific case comes to mind at the moment.

Because of some graphical glitches I had while drawing onto a JPanel and Canvas way back, I searched around for a way to to triple buffering instead of double buffering. After going through a number of pages and a lot of trouble, I found out that a Canvas can be set to use triple buffering, but the JPanel can't as far as I saw. Although this may be wrong.

Here's a snip of the code that's needed to run every time the render method of the Canvas is run.

http://pastebin.com/zsqhDyEb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use Swing components instead: they provide much more flexibility:

```
JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
bar.setBackground(Color.RED);
bar.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

You should have no problems integrating Swing components with existing AWT components.

Comment: I would use Swing if I was able to, but the Frame I'm using is an AWT component and won't work with the JMenuBar as far as I know. That's why I'm going through the trouble of trying to get this to work.

Comment: @Valkryst, `Frame` is also `Container`, so you can add a `JMenuBar` (which is also AWT `Component`) as a subcomponent instead of using the `setMenuBar`. But probably the better way is to refactor it and throw away that old AWT stuff.

Comment: Oh, I never thought to try it that way. Most of the pages that I looked to always seemed to use setMenuBar because they're all using Swing instead of AWT.

As I've said in another comment, I'm trying to go through the code now and swap things over to Swing. Thanks for the information.